# How to get the WC_Product Object when using a WP_Query in WooCommerce

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to list my products using `WP_Query`.
I have used a query such as the following one:

```
$slider_products_q = new WP_Query([
     'posts_per_page'    => 8,
      'post__in'          => $slides_product_ids,
      'post_type'         => 'product',
      'orderby'           => 'date',
      'order'             => 'DESC'
]);
```

It works perfectly, however when I want to access WooCommerce methods inside the loop such as `get_html_price` it becomes a bit tricky.

I have managed to handled it using this way, yet the performace is not good and the query takes about '0.7' seconds to load up.

This is how I loop though each item:

```
if ($slider_products_q->have_posts()):
   while($slider_products_q->have_posts()):
       $slider_products_q->the_post();         
       $product_id = get_the_ID();
       global $product;
       ...
```

Then I could call `$product->get_price_html();` method.

I also did try to query products using Woocommerce methods but since they load up a lot of custom attributes the query takes even much more time.

Any suggestion of how to improve this?

By the way I only care about using Woocommerce methods such as `get_price_html`. 
Attributes or custom terms are not necessary at all.

Answer (score 2):

The `global $product;` doesn't work in a custom `WP_Query`, instead use `wc_get_product()` like:

```
if ($slider_products_q->have_posts()):
   while($slider_products_q->have_posts()):
       $slider_products_q->the_post();         
       $product_id = get_the_ID();
       $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

       $price_html = $product->get_price_html()
       // ...
```

Now you can use any `WC_Product` methods on `$product` variable.

Alternatively, you could use a [`WC_Product_query`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query).

Comment: If I use `wc_get_product` it will be disastrous, since another query is going to take place beside the WP_Query.

I will try using `WC_Product_query` hope it does help, but if this method loads attributes while getting products, another massive query will happen considering my website have more that 20000 attributes in woocommerce.

Comment: @MMT So use directly a `WC_Product_Query` instead. There is no other ways if you want to use methods as `get_price_html()`…

Comment: I will try it and inform you of the results.

Comment: I had tested your solution but mine was much faster

Comment: @MMT What solution? Your question is not about a faster solution, but about how to use WC_Product methods on a WP_Query and in your code how to get the WC_Product Object… My answer answers that.

Comment: unfortunately @fuxia changed my original question